# Is there any function available in blue prism to get the previous months value from given date?

Tags: blueprism

Is there any function available in blue prism to get previous month value from given date?

Comment: In the future, please know that questions here are expected to include a good-faith effort on your part by showing us what code you've tried or research you've performed, and where *specifically* you're getting stuck in those attempts, per the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Today()` within the `AddMonths()` function and passing a negative number for the `Months` parameter to return the date exactly one month:

```
AddMonths(Today(), -1)
```

If you need the name of the month (or other representation) you can pass the result to the `FormatDate()` function:

```
FormatDate(AddMonths(Today(), -1), "MMMM")
```